# setContentView(R.layout.main); Gives error from start

Tags: android

I'm just starting to develop with android, and a followed a tutorial on google to get everything set up. I'm using eclipse and I have both the android sdk and the eclipse plugin installed, but when I create a new Android Project, I get an error on this line from the start.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

It Says that the "R" in "R.layout.main" does not exist. Is there class that i need to create or import? I'm really confused because i have thoroughly searched and cannot find anyone else with this issue.

Comment: You need to import _your.package.name.R_

Comment: It's autogenerated, check the _gen_ folder for your project.

Comment: That usually indicates that there is an error in one of your resources, and the project isn't building correctly. Check your resources for errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is quite a common mistake .
make sure that at the top of your java file of the activity , the import is not of android.R.layout (or whatever) ,since it should import the R of your own app (which is inside the gen folder).

if you still have problems with that , try to delete the gen folder ,  make sure the layout file is ok (meaning it's a correct android layout file, without any mistakes), make sure all of the resources (all images, sounds , xml files , all that are in /res) have only the legal characters in their files names (which means they are lowercase english ,optionally with "_" and digits, but no more) , clean the project , and then import the generated file .

you can also use CTRL+1 on the red underline of the R that it complains about , and choose the one of your project.

Comment: What should it say? My package name is com.hello.world

Comment: well , if the app package name is "com.hello.world" , it should be : import com.hello.world.R;

Comment: Thanks you, this worked. Had to delete the gen folder than clean the project!

Comment: had the same issue, deleting the gen folder and the bin folder then rebuild the app and it works

Answer (score 4):

Bad resources can cause your android project not to generate R.java file. Try to check /res/layout and see if there are errors on **any** of your layouts.

Also try to get rid of `import android.R.*;`

Then go to Project > Clean

Answer (score 0):

Usually a main layout file is auto-generated for you when you create an Android project.

Make sure that you have a file named "main.xml" inside of your res/layouts folder.
Assuming that you do, try Project->Clean.

Comment: Tried that, no luck. Also I have that file in my res/layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project and click **Fix Project Properties**.

If that doesn't work, then you either have an error somewhere in your project that is preventing your `R.java` class from being generated, or eclipse is being dumb and you need to perform a **Project --> Clean** and/or restart the IDE all together.

Answer (score 0):

Add main.xml in res->layout
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" > 
</LinearLayout>
```

OR Layout->New-android XML file

clean and Build Project

Answer (score 0):

You can import the package like so:

```
import com.example.kaushal.checkbox.R;
```

and then rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

just go to build option and click on rebuild project. This might work. :)

Answer (score -1):

i had also getting this issue just import package as your previous.
Example if your main page package name is import com.example.chephotel.R;
just copy and paste same in your newly created java file